# How to use Guava Optional in this scenario

Tags: java, guava, option-type

I have a scenario which I want to use Guava Optional, but there is problem:

The method is like this:

```
private static void method(Optional<Object> myOptional) {
   if(myOptional.isPresent()) {
       ....
   }
}
```

The myOptional can contain non-null value, null value, or absent(). A null is a valid input in this scenario.

In the method, I want to process non-null value and null value using differnt ways, but ignore absent value.

However, if I use isPresent here, the null value will be ignored as well. But if I use "get" method, the absent value will throw exception. If I use orNull, the absent value also returns as null.

I am not sure what I shall do here. But I think the reason to create Optional is to differentiate null and absent so that null becomes a valid meaningful value. But it looks like there is no method in Optional that allows me to achieve my usecase.

Can anyone help? Thanks.

Comment: I recommend _not_ using `Optional` as the parameter type of a method. It's best as a _return_ type. If you're using it as a parameter, you have better options... for example, two overloads of your method, `method()` and `method(Object)`.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that.

The javadoc says it explicitly: an `Optional` may contain a **non null reference**. Never a `null` one.

What you can do is create an `Optional.fromNullable(whatever).orNull()`. But an `Optional` will never differentiate a null value from absent, since it is not what it is meant to do!